# Expression for potential vector of a central field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, electromagnetism, curl, divergence-theorem

I know that for the central field
$$
{\bf F(x)}=\alpha\cdot\frac{\bf x}{|{\bf x}|^{3}}=\alpha\cdot\left(\frac{x_{1}}{|{\bf x}|^{3}},\frac{x_{2}}{|{\bf x}|^{3}},\frac{x_{3}}{|{\bf x}|^{3}}\right)
$$
holds $\nabla\cdot{\bf F(x)}=\delta_{0}$, where $\alpha$ is a constant, $|\bf x|$ is the euclidian norm (*i.e.* $|{\bf x}|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ ) and $\delta_{0}$ is the Dirac delta. If one consider a region of the space that doesn't surround the origin, then $\bf F(x)$ should have a potential vector $\bf A$ such that $\nabla \times {\bf A}={\bf F}$, because in this case we can safely say that $\nabla\cdot{\bf F(x)}=0$.
But is there an analytical expression for that potential vector? Moreover, my reasonings are correct or am I wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf F = \delta_0$ (up to constants)? That's true only for an inverse-square force.

Comment: I have an inverse square law, maybe my notation is a bit odd

Comment: With the $F$ in there, it's no longer inverse-square in general!

Comment: I wrote an useless F after the =, thanks for the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $\alpha = 1$, here is a vector potential for $\mathbf F$. It is defined and smooth off the $z$-axis.

Set $$\mathbf A = \frac1{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}}\big(yz,-xz,0\big).$$

The answer is very non-unique. Indeed, you can find this solution, as I did, by looking for $\mathbf A = (P,Q,R)$ with $R=0$. Now find other solutions with, correspondingly, $P=0$ and $Q=0$. Any convex linear combination of these three will be another solution. Of course, the domain of such a vector field will be only the complement of all three coordinate axes.

Comment: Why is a convex linear combination needed, instead of a generic linear one? Due to the value of $\alpha$?

Comment: Right. If $\nabla\times\mathbf A_1 = \nabla\times\mathbf A_2 = \nabla\times\mathbf A_3 = \mathbf F$, then $\nabla\times(c_1\mathbf A_1+c_2\mathbf A_2+c_3\mathbf A_3) = (c_1+c_2+c_3)\mathbf F$, right?